# Has Shoji Kawamori ever commented on Robotech?

Tags: macross, robotech

Harmony Gold infamously dubbed Macross as the first part of the Robotech saga. Character names, music, and some story elements were changed or removed completely. This has long been a matter of contention between the fans of both series, as well as having a lot of legal ramifications.

But has the creator of Macross, Shoji Kawamori, ever commented on the existence of Robotech?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robotech) :

> Series writer/actor Greg Snegoff said in an interview on the now-defunct Shadow Chronicles News fansite that, "afterward, we received compliments from the Japanese who thought our dialogue and stories were better than the original". However, Animag magazine (issue 11) and Animerica magazine (issue 9, volume 4) reports that the staff of Macross at Studio Nue and Artland, such as the original story creator and mecha designer **Shoji Kawamori** and chief director **Noboru Ishiguro**, expressed their concern over the **Robotech** adaptation, and surprise at its differences.

So it seems that he raised concerns about the same, and acknowledged the presence of **Robotech**

Further can be noticed in the interview clip [here](http://www.awopodcast.com/?bloggerURL=/008/05/bonus-interview-with-noboru-ishiguro.html)

Answer (score 1):

According to this, he was once asked in an spanish interview about it and his answer was

> does Robotech exist? What is that? Does Macross II exist?

http://rdfhqcommunicationscenter.yuku.com/topic/1583/Shoji-Kawamori-does-Robotech-exist#.WFNQHPl97IU

Edit: 01/05/2017

I found more about this recently. Very interesting actually

> “When it comes to Robotech, it's difficult to comment. It's not as
>   though I have sat through the whole series. Not to mention that it
>   combines three separate series Macross, Southern Cross and Mospeada.
>   So it feels a bit forced as a result.”
>
> “At the same time, this was an opportunity for our work to be shown to
>   the world and for that I am thankful. However, because the partial
>   change in the story was made without approval from us, the original
>   authors, it still produces an uncomfortable feeling after all these
>   years.”
>
> "As for the recently announced live action Robotech movie, I welcome
>   the opportunity to work on it but that request has yet to come."

https://www.forbes.com/sites/olliebarder/2015/12/10/shoji-kawamori-the-creator-hollywood-copies-but-never-credits/#5a3eb4d63a0f